# What is the latest protractor version that works with 51 version chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

How can I know the latest protractor version that can work with 51 version chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Wish if there is any easier way to figure that out but there is none. Its at best trial and error effort.

The only way that i can think of is going by the chrome release dates [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) (if you trust wikipedia).

Then portractor release dates [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases).

Start from a protractor release that was just prior to Chrome52 release date and try it.

From the question, looks like you dont have the webdriver information either. The drivers need to be downloaded for that particular Chrome version. See if they are available [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). Its again trial and error based on the date of driver release you find in there.

If not from the starting of time, little bit of Webdriver version to Chrome version information can be found [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

To download a specific version of webdriver, use

```
npx webdriver-manager clean
npx webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=76.0.3809.68
```

Having said all that, i am not optimistic at all that you are looking at an easy task :(

Good luck...